# Segmentation fault:11, when I run C code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am new in C programming. When I write a c code about sorting integers. I got a **Segmentation fault: 11.** I search the related articles, but seems too confusing for me. Here follows first part of my code(get 10 input integers, and derive all the odd integers). Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;

int main(void)
{
int array[10];
int previous[10],odd[10];


printf("Pls enter 10 nums\n");
while(i < 10)
{
    scanf("%d", &array[i++]);
}

for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
{
printf("%d ", array[i]);    
}

for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
{
    int a,j;
    if(array[i] % 2 == 1)
    {
        previous[a] = i;
        odd[j] = array[i];
        a++;
        j++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to learn to use a debugger and also to put the warning level of your compiler higher. It should have warned you that the variables `a` and `j` aren't initialized, so anything can happen there, including segfaults.

Comment: Thanks.  :) Is there any resource to learn debugger or increase warning level?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the variables `a` and `j`. In C you cannot be sure that when you declare them they will have the value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give `i` and `a` initial values you will likely be attempting to go beyond the bounds of your array.